# Angular JS: value not updated after assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope that is not updated after assignment inside a factory http call.

```
    var form = {}
    var requestForm = {}
    requestForm['name'] = $scope.brand.name;
    requestForm['country'] = $scope.brand.countryCode;
```

So I'm setting a `$scope.mergeId` as my initializer as value 0, then the `tableFactory.setMergeRequest` will call a http call in the factory file and will return an object, with a boolean and an id #.

```
    $scope.mergeId = 0;
    //set merge request/id
    tableFactory.setMergeRequest(requestForm).then(function(data){

        if(data.mergeRequestStatus){

          console.log(data);

          $scope.mergeId = data.insertedRequestId; //456


        }else{
          console.log('no merge id');
        }

    });

    form['mergeId'] = $scope.mergeId;
```

The boolean will be true, and it should assign the id (456) to the `$scope.mergeId`.  Then that scope will be used to assign the `form['mergeId']` variable that will be used in another http call.

When I check the console, the form variable is at zero so it's not updated.  I took out the initializer but then it's saying is undefined.  The http call is sending back data, it's just the scope is not being updated.

Has anyone gone through this issue before? Should I change the setup for this http call?  I tried to this, but it's not setting the right value, it's setting an object.

```
form['mergeId'] = tableFactory.setMergeRequest(requestForm).then(function(data){

        if(data.mergeRequestStatus){

          return data.insertedRequestId

        }else{

          return null
        }

    });
```

the response I got from this way, is a d, how do i get the value?

[image]

Please help, I've been stuck with this issue for a while.  Your help will be appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

This is the http call where `tableFactory.setMergeRequest` is triggered.

```
var setMergeRequest = function(object){

      var mergeRequestCall = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: CONFIG.PYTHON_API_END_POINT + '/api/mergerequest',
          data: object
      }

      var d = $q.defer();

      $http(mergeRequestCall)
      .success(function(response){
        d.resolve(response);
      }).error(function(response){
        d.resolve([]);
      });


      return d.promise;
    }
```

The response is :

```
{
  "insertedRequestId": 456,
  "mergeRequestStatus": true
}
```

Comment: when do you want to hit the second http, after getting the response from first http, right?

Comment: @AgamBanga yes that is correct

Comment: you can look into `promise chain` in javascript. Your problem is the use case of `chaning in JS`

Comment: @AgamBanga I see what you are saying, and you're right the problem was the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value where the promise is resolved, not set the value to the function

```
tableFactory.setMergeRequest(requestForm).then(function(data){
        if(data.mergeRequestStatus){
          form['mergeId'] = data.insertedRequestId;
        }else{
          form['mergeId'] = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried this, and I saw  the value.  Now the problem is the backend is saying is missing the merge id.  I did a curl request and the backend recognized it.  That leads me to believe this is a front end issue.

Comment: Could you share the tableFactory.setMergeRequest() and the response json

Comment: I added the function and the response